# Position a WPF control absolute, above all other elements

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-4.0, wpf-graphics

I need to display a stripe at the top of my main window to hide unwanted artefacts. This is an urgent workaround, but would be nice to know as well. I have two main grid columns, but would like to position the stripe at 0,0 relative to the client area of the main window and have it display across both grid columns.

Do I have to resort to direct windows API calls or is this possible in WPF, with some sort of layering or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work, with a fixed height Grid at the top above all other child elements:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- your column definitions -->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- your regular child elements -->

    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Height="20">
        <!-- the stripe content goes here -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```